# can we define pytest hooks outside conftest.py?

Tags: python, hook, pytest

i did some research in the sites below but i haven't still figured out if we can define pytest hooks (e.g. pytest_runtest_makereport) other than in the conftest.py file.
basically, what i am trying to figure out is if i avoid duplicating conftest.py files by defining a hook inside a base class, for example, so other projects (or classes) consuming this base class can inherit these hooks.

thanks a lot.

references i've used:

- http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html
- http://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html
- several other stack overflow pages talking about hooks

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way would be to move this hooks into an appropriate plugin, but you can force a module to be interpreted as one by declaring a `pytest_plugins` variable in a `conftest` file in your project:

```
pytest_plugins = ['myproject.plugin'] # myproject.plugin contains hooks
```

Or you can use the `-p` flag to `py.test`:

```
py.test -p myproject.module
```

Note that the last option can be configured in your `pytest.ini` as well:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -p myproject.module
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to achieve that, just put all pytest hooks in a python file, and import it to the conftest.py file in your test pillar folder.

For example: in conftest.py of your test pillar

```
from custom_hooks import *
```

Then you can reuse all hooks.

And if you want to overwrite one, just define it again in conftest.py.