# How to use command line arguments in pytest without modifying conftest.py

Tags: python, pytest

I need to pass the path to 2 files using command line arguments in a pytest.

I have looked into many answers but they all require modifying conftest.py
[How to pass arguments in pytest by command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880259/how-to-pass-arguments-in-pytest-by-command-line)

Is there anyway to add arguments that can be used in a test script without modifying conftest.py?

Ideally, I would like to do this within the test file but it's not necessarily required. I have tried to import argparse in the test file to add the additional arguments but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

pytest hooks, including `pytest_addoption` must be defined in either a plugin or a `conftest.py` file

see also:

- [the documentation on plugin discovery](https://pytest.org/en/6.2.x/writing_plugins.html?#plugin-discovery-order-at-tool-startup)
- [can we define pytest hooks outside conftest.py](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28753000/812183)

---

disclaimer: I'm a pytest core dev